# Visual Studio & ffmpeg : Building FFmpeg in visual studio - 'ffmpeg.obj'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I am new here and I am trying to link ffmpeg with visual studio following some guides like :

- http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Linking-to-FFmpeg-with-Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b

I added librairies in the project propreties :

- In C/C++ --> General --> Additional Include Directories
- In Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories
- In Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies

But I have encountered the following problem :

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'ffmpeg.obj'

I tried to add double quotes around path of the libraries but it hasn't changed the outcome.

Nevertheless, I can't find anything about 'ffmpeg.obj'
What is this file ? What could I change to avoid this error ?

Comment: Do you actually _have_ a file named `ffmpeg.obj` ? This is basic troubleshooting procedures: if file A can't be found, either it doesn't exist, or you're not looking in the right place. The solution will depend on the problem you have.

Comment: Indeed i don't have a file named ffmpeg.obj and I can't figure out why Visual needs one.

Comment: It needs one because it didn't find `ffmpeg.lib` in the linker paths. When you specify `ffmpeg` as a linker dependency and a `.lib` file is not found in the locations you told the linker to look the next option is to look for a `.obj`. I expect you typed `ffmpeg` as an additional dependency not `ffmpeg.lib`

Comment: I haven't a ffmpeg.lib. In linker dependency (and especially Linker --> input --> additional dependencies) I have : libavcodec, libavdevice, libavfilter, libavformat, libavutil, libswresample and libswscale

Comment: What exactly did you type there? Your problem is most likely you typed something wrong in the 3 settings.

Comment: Linker --> input --> additional dependencies :

"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin\avcodec-59.lib"
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin\avdevice-59.lib"
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin\avfilter-8.lib"
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin\avformat-59.lib"
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin\avutil-57.lib"
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin\swresample-4.lib"
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin\swscale-6.lib"

Comment: This is somewhat odd. I still expect something is typed wrong in one of the linker settings.

Comment: Besides I wrote :

In project properties --> C/C++ --> General --> Additional Include Directories 
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\include"

and In Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib"

Answer (score 1):

All well by replacing

> Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib"

by

> Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin"

where the libraries are.